# how much is 1% fuzz in imagemagick?

Tags: math, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm working on a script and Imagemagick, to search for specific colors on images.

I'm thinking about using fuzz in the search, but can't find any information about how much for example 1%fuzz is?

```
if I'm running:
convert "images.png"          -fill black +opaque #440000  -fuzz 1%       \( +clone -evaluate set 0 \)    -metric AE -compare             -format "%[distortion]" info:>/tmp/rip.hex.data
```

.. and searching for color #440000, and add 1% fuzz on that, then, what's the 1% of?

1% of 256?

1% of the image's total colors?

1% of...?

Comment: If you are still not getting it, maybe look at the RGB colour cube, and think of 100% fuzz as being the distance from the black vertex to the white one https://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=https://www.scratchapixel.com/images/upload/color/rgbcube.png&imgrefurl=https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/digital-imaging/colors/color-space&tbnid=SlANVILdQ7iHYM&vet=1&docid=8ogvkP00n9O-_M&w=300&h=313&itg=1&hl=en-gb&source=sh/x/im

Comment: So, your #440000 is a point on the edge of the RGB colour cube 68/255 of the way between black and red. Now imagine a tiny sphere with that point at its centre and a radius 1% of the distance from black to white in that RGB cube. Your fuzz incorporates all the colours in that sphere.

Answer (score 4):

In ImageMagick, fuzz is computed as the root mean squared difference between two colors.

```
fuzz = rmse = sqrt( (rdiff^2 + gdiff^2 + bdiff^2)/3 )
```

where r,g,b are in quantum range for your compile -- typically Q16 or 16-bits, so 0 to 65535.

```
So fuzz in percent is 100*fuzz/65535
```

So 1% fuzz would be .01*65535 = 655.35 gray levels out of 65535 as measured by the rmse formula.

Comment: I think I asked a question where I, even thou getting correct answers, will never fully understand..

Comment: In effect it is 1% of the total possible difference in color. If you want the equivalent in 8-bit color then it is 0.01*255 = 2.55 gray levels summed of the r,g,b channels so about 2.55/3 per color channel or a little less than 1 gray level per color channel or 1 part in 255 per color channel.

Comment: ehh, okay not that I'm understanding, which I'm not, so 1% fuzz ..  let's make it simple so a moran like me can understand, 1%fuzz on #440000, can a person see the difference?

Comment: Visually, no.  That would be like #470000 vs #440000 or #450101 vs #440000.

Comment: is there anyway to get imagemagick to create an image with the color #440000 and create the other colorcodes (1%fuzz) (in one image) so you can visually "see" the span between the colors?

Comment: `convert -size 200x200 xc:"#440000" xc:"#470000" +append fuzz_1pct.png`. Because the two color swatches are side-by-side, you can barely see the difference. But if they were separate images, you likely would not see any difference. Though that depends upon your vision.

Answer (score 1):

It's 1% of the quantum range. So if you installed ImageMagick Q16, it would be 2<sup>16</sup> * 0.01. Or about `65536 * 0.01 = 655.36`.

Comment: so, the color could deviate 655 "steps" from #440000 ? I'm not really getting it..